# Removing a set of letters from a string

Tags: postgresql

I want to remove  the vowels from the email id. Which function should I use?
I am trying to find the difference  between `translate` and `replace` in postgresql
but didn't get the exact difference

Comment: For tips on asking better Stack Overflow questions I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. For PostgreSQL specific questions also read "how to ask good questions" under http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info . To help others who find your question later, to prevent misunderstandings, and to make it easier to answer your question more quickly it's good to include versions, sample data, expected results, etc.

Answer (score 50):

`translate()` replaces a *set* of single characters (passed as a string) with another *set* of characters (also passed as a string), for example:

```
translate('abcdef', 'ace', 'XYZ') --> 'XbYdZf'
```

`replace()` replaces occurrences of a *string* of arbitrary length with another *string*:

```
replace('abcdef', 'bc', 'FOO') --> 'aFOOdef'
```

Answer (score 17):

In this case you probably [actually want `regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

Assuming by "vowel" you mean "Western European (English) language vowel letters" you might write:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('BobbafEtt@nerd.com', '[aeiou]', '', 'gi');
```

the `gi` in the fourth argument says "apply this regular expression **g**lobally to the whole input string not just to the first match, and make it case **i**nsensitive".

Remember that `w` and `y` are sometimes vowel-sounds, depending on their context, too. You won't be able to handle that with a regexp so it depends on whether or not you care for this purpose.

You're less likely to need to deal with other character sets if you're working with email addresses so a regexp might be OK for this.

In most cases mangling words with regular expressions would not be a good approach, though; for example, Russian in the Cyrillic alphabet uses `A Э У О Ы Я Е Ё Ю И` as vowels. Additionally, depending on the language, the same letter in the same script might or might not be a vowel! [Keep reading here for more than you ever wanted to know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel#Written_vowels).

Answer (score 9):

## TLDR;

To eliminate all vowels from an "e-mail id", the simplest expression I can think of is:

- `translate(email_id, 'aeiou', '')`

## In detail

To complement Bohemians's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691579/postgres-removing-a-set-of-letters-from-a-string/60817160#17691662):

Both `replace()` and `translate()` can be used to:

- replace characters
- eliminate characters

And both functions accept three parameters:

- A string being `manipulated`: the return string will be a (possibly) modified version of this string
- A `from` string, containing something to be found in the `manipulated` string
- A `to` string, containing something that might be present on the output string depending on the function used, the `manipulated` string, and the `from` string

The difference is that `replace()` can only replace whole sequences of characters, that must be found in the `manipulated` string in a specific order:

```sql
postgres=> select replace('foobarbaz', 'bar', 'FRED');
  replace   
------------
 fooFREDbaz
(1 row)
```

Even if replacing them with an empty string:

```sql
postgres=> select replace('foobarbaz', 'bar', '');
 replace 
---------
 foobaz
(1 row)
```

But if the characters in the `from` string cannot be found in that specific order inside the `manipulated` string, `replace()` returns a string identical to the `manipulated` one:

```sql
postgres=> select replace('foobarbaz', 'rab', '');
 replace 
---------
 foobarbaz
(1 row)
```

`translate()` on the other hand, deals not with a sub-string of characters that must be found in a specific sequence on the string being manipulated, but with **sets** of characters:

Each **character** in the `manipulated` string that is present in the `from` string is mapped to another character in the **same position** in the `to` string as it was found in the `from` string:

```sql
postgres=> select translate('foobarbaz', 'bar', '123');
 translate 
-----------
 foo12312z

postgres=> select translate('foobarbaz', 'rab', '123');
 translate 
-----------
 foo32132z
(1 row)
```

In the first `translate()` example above, the following mapping happened:

- `'b'` -> `'1'` (for both occurrences of `'b'`)
- `'a'` -> `'2'` (for both occurrences of `'a'`)
- `'r'` -> `'3'` (for the single occurrence `'3'`)

Although `translate()` can be used to map characters as above, it can also be used to eliminate sets of characters. This happens if the `to` string is shorter than the `from` string:

```sql
postgres=> select translate('foobarbaz', 'rab', '1');
 translate 
-----------
 foo1z
(1 row)

postgres=> select translate('foobarbaz', 'rab', '');
 translate 
-----------
 fooz
(1 row)
```

In the first example above, the following mapping happened:

- `'r'` -> `'1'` (for the single occurrence of `'r'`)
- `'b'` -> eliminated (for both occurrences of `'b'`)
- `'a'` -> eliminated (for both occurrences of `'a'`)

Whereas in the second example above, all occurrences of the characters `'r'`, `'a'` and `'b'` are eliminated since the `to` string is empty.

So, to eliminate vowels from an email id, you can do:

- `translate(email_id, 'aeiou', '')`

As long as all you care are about `ascii` vowels, as mentioned by Craig Ringer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691579/postgres-removing-a-set-of-letters-from-a-string/60817160#17691877).